# UICollectionViewCell has no member present

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UIViewController` and `UICollectionViewController` in my project. I use custom `UICollectionViewCell` class for this `UICollectionView`. The problem is that I'm trying to present another `UIViewController` on button tap. This button's code is in the custom `UICollectionViewCell` class, that causes next mistake:

> Value of type 'myCollectionViewCellClass' has no member 'present'

So is there a way to tell my `UIViewController` to present the new view?

Comment: You use delegates and handle it in the view controller.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. This question unfortunately was already answered and I just used it :)